# Convert Chinese docx files to markdown with Pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, docx, pandoc

I am batch converting documents that are primarily written in Chinese from docx to markdown using Pandoc within a Powershell script. However, all Chinese characters are being converted to question marks - "?"

The command I am using is

```
pandoc.exe -f  docx -t $converter-simple_tables-multiline_tables-grid_tables+pipe_tables -i $fullexportpath -o "$($fullfilepathwithoutextension).md" --wrap=none --atx-headers --extract-media="$($mediaPath)"
```

It works perfectly for English documents, so I presume I just need to add some sort of modifier to handle Chinese characters.

I have seen various posts about needing to use --latex-engine=xelatex and/or -V CJKmainfont="Font Name" (I've been using it with "Microsoft YaHei", the font in Word), but no combinations of these seems to matter (in fact, using --latex-engine at all breaks the conversion). It seems that they are for converting to PDF.

Any suggestions?

Edit: the issue was not with Pandoc but with the script I was using that did some find and replace conversion. Works fine with English but not Chinese characters.

Comment: question mark chars sounds like you just don't have the font in your text editor to display chinese chars...

Comment: Thanks, but I can copy and paste the Chinese characters into the text editor (VS Code) and they display just fine.

Interestingly, the filename properly displays the Chinese characters. So its a Pandoc issue rather than a Windows/Powershell one

Comment: can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the script: https://github.com/nixsee/ConvertOneNote2MarkDown


It exports from OneNote to docx, which it does just fine with any chinese characters. It then converts the docx to markdown using pandoc, and makes some other modifications to the file - this is where the problem is. 


You could either input some Chinese characters (事件基本信息 模板) into a Onenote page and try the full process, or paste them into a docx file and try running Pandoc directly with the command I pasted in the original question (modifying for file location etc... as appropriate). Thanks!

Comment: @mb21, it looks like the problem is not with Pandoc, but with the script doing some find and replace actions. It works fine with English, but is not playing well with Chinese characters. I'll have to tinker around... Thanks for the help!